# RabbitMQ - Send messages with common property to same consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

### Background

I have a distributed system with many machines. I have two types of applications - Producer and Consumer. To be more specific - a single producer and multiple consumers. Each "consumer machine" has multiple consumers.

All the messages in the system are going to same queue. Message looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": "Thisismyid",
    "CacheId": "CacheID"
    ...
}
```

My consumers are applying a cache strategy in order to process queue messages faster. Once the message was downloaded by the consumer, it being checked if the `CacheId` is already cached previously. If yes - continue. If no - cache it and continue.

All the consumers on same machine are sharing the same cache repository.

### The problem

This structure is "optimal" when I have 1 consumer. Since, same machine cache the items and use it multiple times.

As the number of consumers is going up - the efficiency of the cache is going down. Because its more likely
that an item will be downloaded by node that wasn't has a ready to use cache.

### The Question

How to use RabbitMQ to "route" messages with same same `CacheId` to be processes by same consumer\machine to increase efficiency? What is the "cost" in terms of RabbitMQ resources?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with a topic exchange: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-dotnet.html

But this would quickly get complicated if you have many `CacheId`.

But I would use a centralized cache instead. Could be Redis: https://redis.io/